# index into Python dict with list to get a list, as with a Perl hash

Tags: python, perl, dictionary, hash

Perl has a construct (called a "hash slice" as Joe Z points out) for indexing into a hash with a list to get a list, for example:

```
%bleah = (1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c');
print join(' ', @bleah{1, 3}), "\n";
```

executed gives:

```
a c
```

the simplest, most readable way I know to approach this in Python would be a list comprehension:

```
>>> bleah = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> print ' '.join([bleah[n] for n in [1, 3]])
a c
```

because:

```
>>> bleah[[1, 2]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

is there some other, better way I'm missing? perhaps in Python3, with which I haven't done much yet? and if not, does anyone know if a PEP has already been submitted for this? my google-fu wasn't able to find one.

"it isn't Pythonic": yes, I know, but I'd like it to be. it *is* concise and readable, and since it will never be Pythonic to index into a dict with an unhashable type, having the exception handler iterate over the index for you instead of barfing wouldn't break most current code.

note: as was pointed out in comments, this test case could be rewritten as a list, obviating use of a dict altogether, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: BTW, the name for Perl's feature as you're using it above is "hash slice".

Comment: How about using a list for the job instead of a dictionary?

Comment: in this case I could, but this is just an illustrative test case.

Comment: I think something like that would be nice, but what should be the result? a list of values or items? a sub-dict? I think it should be better using `bleah.items([1,3])` returning `[('1','a'),('3','c')]` or `bleah.values([1,3])` returning `['a', 'c']`

Comment: what I would *like* to get would be a list of values: `['a', 'c']`, as in the Perl example.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Please check my answer. You might want to use `itemgetter`

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. IMO it's not an improvement in conciseness or readability, and it requires an import rather than being intrinsic to the language syntax.

Comment: I don't know if any of the answers have considered this, but in Perl a hash slice is an lvalue. So for example, you can assign to keys "a" and "c" in a hash like this: `@hash{"a", "c"} = split "|", "foo|bar"`

Comment: good point. I should probably modify `__setitem__` as well, but for now my `__getitem__` override serves my needs.

Comment: done. that was easy! thank you @tobyink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for now, I'm taking Hyperboreus's suggestion in the comments and overriding `__getitem__`, but I still think it makes sense to have it be default dict behavior:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ cat /tmp/sliceable.py; echo ---; python /tmp/sliceable.py
'SliceableDict test'
import sys, os
class SliceableDict(dict):
 def __init__(self, d = {}):
  super(SliceableDict, self).__init__(d)
 def __getitem__(self, index):
  try:
   return super(SliceableDict, self).__getitem__(index)
  except TypeError:
   return [super(SliceableDict, self).__getitem__(x) for x in index]
 def __setitem__(self, index, value):
  try:
   super(SliceableDict, self).__setitem__(index, value)
  except:
   for i in range(len(index)):
    super(SliceableDict, self).__setitem__(index[i], value[i])
d = SliceableDict({1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'})
print d[2]
print d[[1, 3]]
d[[1, 3]] = ['x', 'y']
print d
---
b
['a', 'c']
{1: 'x', 2: 'b', 3: 'y'}
```

(modified to add lvalue capability as per tobyink's comment above -- jc 2013-12-12)

Comment: On the one hand I think it is a useful and nice idea (+1), on the other hand `d[(1,3)]` and `d[[1,3]]` would return/mean different things. I am not sure if it is worth the possible confusion…

Answer (score 5):

The best way I could think of, is to use `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
bleah = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
getitems = itemgetter(1, 3)
print getitems(bleah)
```

So, if you want to pass a list of indices then you can unpack the arguments, like this (Thanks @koffein for pointing this out :))

```
getitems = itemgetter(*[1, 3])
```

You can then `join` like this

```
print ' '.join(getitems(bleah))
```

or simply

```
print ' '.join(itemgetter(1, 3)(bleah))
```

Comment: +1 Nice. But the OP wanted to pass a list, so you could use `itemgetter(*[1,3])` instead. (or add it)

Comment: more directly, you could just do `print ' '.join(itemgetter(1,3)[bleah])`

Comment: @thefourtheye first, `[bleah]` in my comment was a typo, meant `(bleah)`.  Second, no need for a list, but if you have them in a list already (e.g. a variable instead of literal keys) you could use the `*` to unpack it into individual arguments to `itemgetter`.

Comment: I tried it, and itemgetter() returned a tuple. sure, it's easy to write list(itemgetter(1, 3)(bleah)) but that adds one more bit of cruft to the clean solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your dict has consecutive integer indices, then you can rebuild it as a list and use

```
bleah[1:3]
```

Comment: No, because it is a dict, not a list.

Comment: A dict with integer indices should be easily refactored into a list.

Comment: Hyperboreus, yes but I'm just giving a simple example.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Does in perl `@bleah{1, 4}` mean "keys 1, 2, 3, 4" or "keys 1 and 4"?

Comment: it means: keys 1 and 4

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Then, dear sir, my answer is bullshit. What you can do is overwrite the `__getitem__` (py3) and pass tuples (which are hashable unlike lists: `a[[1,2]]` doesn't work but `a[1,2]` which is `a[(1,2)]` does). Numpy does this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is *marginally* better since you have a default if for some reason an unknown key is passed, and it avoids the unnecessary inner list and imports (as with @thefourtheye's example):

```
bleah = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
print(' '.join(bleah.get(i, '') for i in (1, 3)))
```

If you would just like a list of returned values:

```
list(bleah.get(i) for i in (1, 3))
```

No need for a default value here, as default for `get` is `None`. `None` can't be converted to string which is why I passed in an empty string in the print example.

Comment: this might be useful for some. I generally prefer an exception to be raised when I use a key that doesn't exist.